# compile feathers-mxml.swc using ant mxml produces errors

Tags: starling-framework

we'd like to use mxml with feathers, but every time we run ant mxml we get the following errors. here are the instructions we are using: https://github.com/joshtynjala/feathers/issues/186.

```
c:\Users\Win732\Downloads\feathers-master\feathers-master>ant mxml<br />
Buildfile: c:\Users\Win732\Downloads\feathers-master\feathers-master\build.xml</p>
<p>-prepare:<br />
[delete] Deleting directory c:\Users\Win732\Downloads\feathers-master\feathers-master\output</p>
 <p>-starling:<br />
 [echo] Building starling.swc<br />
 [java] Loading configuration: C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722\AIRSDK\frameworks\flex-config.xml<br />
 [java]<br />
 [java] 175059 bytes written to C:\Users\Win732\Downloads\feathers-master\feathers-master\output\dependencies\starling.swc in 10.868 seconds</p>
<p>mxml:<br />
 [echo] Building feathers-mxml.swc<br />
 [java] Loading configuration file C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\sdks\4.6.0-air3.6\frameworks\flex-config.xml<br />
 [java] C:\Users\Win732\Downloads\feathers-master\feathers-master\source\feathers\core\FocusManager.as(117): col: 13 Error: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to<br />
an unrelated type starling.display:Stage.<br />
 [java]<br />
 [java]                             for(var stage:Stage in STAGE_TO_STACK)    
 [java]                                     ^<br />
 [java]<br />
 [java] C:\Users\Win732\Downloads\feathers-master\feathers- master\source\feathers\controls\supportClasses\TextFieldViewPort.as(754): col:  54 Error: Access of possibly unde<br />
 fined property contentsScaleFactor through a reference with static type   flash.display:Stage.<br />
 [java]<br />
 [java]                             nativeScaleFactor =  Starling.current.nativeStage.contentsScaleFactor;<br />
 [java]                                                                                   
 [java]<br />
 [java] C:\Users\Win732\Downloads\feathers-master\feathers- master\source\feathers\controls\text\StageTextTextEditor.as(966): col: 54 Error:  Access of possibly undefined property contentsScaleFactor through a reference with static type   flash.display:Stage.<br />
 [java]<br />
 [java]                             nativeScaleFactor =    Starling.current.nativeStage.contentsScaleFactor;<br />
 [java]                                                                              
 [java]<br />
 [java] C:\Users\Win732\Downloads\feathers-master\feathers-master\source\feathers\controls\text\StageTextTextEditor.as(1487): col: 54 Error: Access of possibly undefined property contentsScaleFactor through a reference with static type flash.display:Stage.<br />
 [java]<br />
 [java]                             nativeScaleFactor = Starling.current.nativeStage.contentsScaleFactor;<br />
 [java]
```

here is our sdk-properties file:

```
The location of the AIR SDK with ASC 2.0<br />
airsdk.root = C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder     4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722/AIRSDK<br />
airsdk.bin = ${airsdk.root}/bin<br />
airsdk.lib = ${airsdk.root}/lib<br />
airsdk.config = ${airsdk.root}/frameworks/flex-config.xml<br />
airsdk.framework = ${airsdk.root}/frameworks</p>
<p># path to compiler jars<br />
asdoc = ${airsdk.lib}/legacy/asdoc.jar<br />
compc = ${airsdk.lib}/compc-cli.jar<br />
mxmlc = ${airsdk.lib}/mxmlc-cli.jar<br />
adt = ${airsdk.lib}/adt.jar</p>
<p># The location of the Flex SDK, to build Feathers with MXML support.<br />
# Override flexsdk.root in sdk.local.properties (create that file if it<br />
# doesn't already exist).<br />
flexsdk.root = C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/sdks/4.6.0-    air3.6<br />
flexsdk.lib = ${flexsdk.root}/lib<br />
flexframework.root = ${flexsdk.root}/frameworks<br />
flexframework.lib = ${flexframework.root}/libs<br />
flex.compc = ${flexsdk.lib}/compc.jar<br />
```

here is our build.properties file:

```
starling.root = ${basedir}/third-party/starling/src<br />
source.root = ${basedir}/source<br />
examples.root = ${basedir}/examples<br />
themes.root = ${basedir}/themes</p>
<p>output.path = ${basedir}/output<br />
dependency.output = ${output.path}/dependencies<br />
swc.output = ${output.path}/swc<br />
docs.output = ${output.path}/documentation<br />
source.output = ${output.path}/source<br />
examples.output = ${output.path}/examples<br />
themes.output = ${output.path}/themes</p>
<p>swf.version = 18</p>
<p>mxml.namespace = library://ns.feathersui.com/mxml</p>
<p>feathers.version = 2.0 PRERELEASE</p>
<p>footer.text = <a href='http://feathersui.com/'>Feathers Website</a> | <a     href='http://wiki.starling-framework.org/feathers/start'>Feathers     Documentation</a> | <a href='https://github.com/joshtynjala/feathers'>Github     Project</a> | <a href='http://forum.starling-    framework.org/forum/feathers'>Support Forum</a><br />
```

we ran into these issues initially, but we're able to fix:
1) /third-party/starling not found
2) point starling.root to /src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per the feathers dev it's a bug:

http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/compile-feathers-mxmlswc-using-ant-mxml-produces-errors

https://github.com/joshtynjala/feathers/issues/876